# What was your favorite feature that was introduced in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php

I'm trying to compile a list of features that were introduced in PHP 5.3.

That I have to check out as time permits. I'd like to do this in the order of usefulness of the features.

The question is subjective, that is the point. I want to end up with a list ordered by what the community liked.

Such a list would hopefully be useful to many who need to do historical research then in the years 2012 or 2013 and I have not been able to find one on SO who did this so far.

Please have named one specific feature per answer, thanks in the past!

Comment: Working on a heavy ERP system I can only think of annoying new features in PHP 5.3 :D

Comment: The clever and consistent use of namespaces. ... Oh, sorry, I thought you said PHP **15**.3...

Comment: 5.3 Changelog might be relevant: http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Late static binding! Finally some sensible way for "normal" inheritance (similar to C or Java).

For example I've created base class that hides all the gory details of accessing the database, object relational mapping, caching etc. and it's child classes define only:

- name of the table
- column names
- parent-child relationships

Comment: @philfreo I have no idea what do you expect :) But here you go: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709568/stackoverflow/php5.3%20lsb.zip

Comment: thanks - that's awesome! seems like that should be a part of a larger framework. which PHP framework is most similar to that? Or if you think it should remain a standalone class, is there somewhere you'll maintain it online?

Comment: @philfreo - glad you like it! I think that http://www.phpactiverecord.org/ is pretty similar & even more powerful. At this moment I don't plan to release my code as open source... Hell, it's just a pet project to keep in touch with PHP because I do something different at work ;) There is high chance it will never go live!

Answer (score 30):

My favorite feature is that the `magic quotes` and `register globals` have been **DEPRECATED**.

Now, any fool *still* using these will get a warning right to their face :)

Comment: Its ironic that PHP 5.3's biggest achievement is the halfway-removal of a feature.

Comment: What's really ironic is that despite all the hate php still runs so many of the webs biggest sites.

Comment: @Ira Baxter A kluge is not a feature--it's a liability.

Comment: @banzaimonkey: at the risk of starting a flame war, I'll note that I think PHP as a whole qualifies as a kluge.

Comment: @Ira Baxter There's a page for that already ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/defend-php-convince-me-it-isnt-horrible

Comment: Maybe those who still use register_globals will just deactivate E_DEPRECATED-Warnings - I mean, it still "Just Works" ...

Comment: Yes it's working in 5.3 but it will stop working in 6.0. Better change code right now (anyway you can't be a real programmer and still use register_globals!).

Comment: While i do believe this will eventually lead to a better quality average, I do not consider it a feature. upvote yes, accept as answer no.

Comment: magic quotes and register globals are not romoved in PHP 6, they are now removed in PHP 5.4! The sooner, the better!

Answer (score 19):

Lambda lambda lambda! Definitely adds flexibility that was missing before.

Comment: `create_function()` is one of the ugliest things I've seen since eval().  Sure you can fake scope by placing variables in string, and build the function with all sorts of crazy, like with for loops appending a string, but it's just...  Then along came Anon Functions, and the world is not such a dark place anymore... except for that damn unfriendly 'use' keyword.

Answer (score 6):

I can't resist: Clearly, adding **GOTO** is the *biggest* thing since sliced bread.

Comment: Shouldn't it be spaghetti instead of sliced bread? :p

Comment: GOTO recalls me of batch coding

Comment: Reminds me of BASIC.  After testing, it appears these labels must follow ''/[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*/i" naming pattern.  Yes, "_" is a valid label (and a valid function and variable name, but that's for another thread).  Thankfully, at least it can't begin with a number, `goto 10`.  Otherwise, how would you fit in yet another crucial line between 99 and 100?  This isn't Apple Basic.  Check out the PHP US man page, second comment.  Gives me shivers.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely [Phar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) files

Comment: Ooooooo...  I missed that one.  Pardon me while I ooo and ahh some more.

Answer (score 6):

I realize you said "one" and "likes", but sometimes a single answer doesn't cut it to put opinion into perspective.  In the wild, you may not see shared hosting services or dev teams use any added features for years to come, so importance is subjective.  These are picked from scanning over PHP's [5.3 changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0).  I could be wrong about which version these features first appeared in, but...

1. **?: Operator:**  Shortcut to the shortcut: *$a = (($a) ? $a : $somethingelse)*.  If $a is loosely false, just resign it to something else: *$a = $a ?: $somethingelse*;  Now just waiting for *$a ?= $somethingelse;*.
   Also, it's like the "OR" operator: *if($a ?: $somethingelse)*, evaluates to true if either $a or $somethingelse are true.  Redundant, but there.

   **__callStatic():**   Now that specialized Singleton class just reduced to a single universal class probably 5 code lines long.

   **Per directory ini files:**   PHP's version of .htaccess files.  Though I have yet to experiment with what ini values are allowed to be switched where.

   **Additional File functions and DNS lookup support for WIN:** at least it would be had WIN obeyed your command to create a `symlink`/shortcut without question since you're the user running the script.

   **array_replace:** Whereas *$a + $b* kept original values, *array_replace($a, $b)* replaces them.

   **Mail logging:** Logging of all mail() calls to check if you're site has been turned into a spam bot.  Though I have yet to test this in the wild to see exactly which mail functions are hooked into (exec()? imap?).

**Missed Chances:**

1. **[FIXED] Calling a method with the same name as the parent class calls the constructor:**  This would've been good to know before.  I think it seems like a useful "feature".

**Dislikes:**

1. Mysqli is still broken.

   WIN32api has been abandoned

   DOTNET() never improved and still pretty much just a fancy alias for COM().  Rumors of PHP and WIN cooperating are just rumors.

Comment: +1 for the COM()/DOTNET() bad support, some of my applications still needing asp to run propriety. Have you ever tried debugging something using a COM() object with php? Most of the times php will completly crash or crash apache, or both and the best thing besides hex code error messages, there's nothing ELSE besides that :P

Comment: @Rodrigo: Why even bother using COM/DOTNET to call these? Just wrap your legacy code in a webservice that you call from your PHP scripts and be done with it.

Comment: @wimvds: The trick is putting together such a thing in a foreign language - something small and compact, easy to build, and acting like a winapi or universal dll accessor/wrapper.  Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

PHP's [DateTime](http://de.php.net/DateTime)-Classes for Timezone-aware Timestamps. It existed before but was improved greatly in 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the late static binding is one of the feature that I will use the most.

https://www.php.net/lsb

With this, it will now be possible to get the maximum out of inheritance.

Comment: example of where this is helpful?

Answer (score 3):

At first I was happy about Lambda in PHP 5.3 but now after several months of developing with 5.3 in in my day to day work, I found that I rarely use Lambda in PHP. Unlike JavaScript where I use closures ALL THE TIME.

The really most useful feature for me in 5.3 is late static binding. Almost every time I have to develop something in 5.2, I really miss it.

And just to make it complete: The worst idea for 5.3 is GOTO. 'Nuff said.

Answer (score 2):

I think PHAR, Lambda and namespace. Theses features seems interesting.

It's hard to answer right now cause we ddidn't use it on a whole project and we already find some strange behavior.

I think next versio of PDT will help programming with PHP 5.3.

Comment: Netbeans already offers 5.3 support (at least in the 6.9RC) I love namespaces (but no so much the implementation php uses) and very interested in PHAR. lambdas are also pretty neat. But... that's three features in one post, should've been three posts for this list.