# Pass a function by reference in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass functions by reference?

Something like this:

```
function call($func){
    $func();
}

function test(){
    echo "hello world!";
}

call(test);
```

I know that you could do `'test'`, but I don't really want that, as I need to pass the function by reference.

Is the only way to do so via anonymous functions?

Clarification: If you recall from C++, you could pass a function via pointers:

```
void call(void (*func)(void)){
    func();
}
```

Or in Python:

```
def call(func):
    func()
```

That's what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to pass the function by reference"?

Comment: This question is devolving into argumentation because you are not clarifying what you mean by "pass by reference" (passing by reference already has a specific meaning which I don't think applies here). Voting to close.

Comment: If you recall from C++, you can pass a function's pointer. That's essentially what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, PHP doesn't have pointers. You can either pass by value or by reference. Neither applies to functions. You're just looking for semantics to pass functions that don't exist. This has nothing to do with "passing by reference".

Comment: You just said: "You can either pass by value or by reference." Then immediately said that I can't do either.

Comment: Passing by reference has a different meaning in PHP, it means if you modify a variable passed by reference the original will be modified. In that sense it's like pointers, but it's not the same. And I said **that does not apply to functions,** since you can't modify functions.

Comment: It's not. I'm trying to accomplish to that, though.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: perhaps let's start from the beginning.  What do you want to achieve by passing the function by reference?  Could you update your post to explain this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554707 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/3234600/166390

Comment: PHP Online Manual has also a page about this: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For what it's worth, how about giving something like this a shot? (Yes, I know it's an *anonymous function* which was *mentioned in the post*, but I was disgruntled at the abundance of *replies that did not mention closures/function-objects at all* so this is mostly a note for people running across this post.)

**I don't use PHP**, but [*using a closure*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) appears to work in **PHP 5.3** (but not PHP 5.2) as [demonstrated here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/klK6gV). **I am not sure what the limitations, if any, there are.** (For all I know the closure will eat your children. You have been warned.)

```
function doIt ($fn) {
  echo "doIt\n";
  return $fn();
}

function doMe () {
  echo "doMe\n";
}

// I am using a closure here.
// There may be a more clever way to "get the function-object" representing a given
// named function, but I do not know what it is. Again, I *don't use PHP* :-)
echo doIt(function () { doMe(); });
```

Happy coding.

Comment: How's this different from what the OP has already proposed himself?

Comment: @deceze It isn't. See the first paragraph which explains the continued existence of the post.

Comment: So you're passing an anonymous function into `doIt`. How does that "pass `doMe` by reference"? Sorry, this answer is as irrelevant as all others, mostly because the question is terrifically unclear.

Comment: @deceze The closure has the *exact same semantics* (as far as I know) when invoked. If other operations were required, on the other hand -- e.g. `function isSameFunction($fn1,$fn2) {...}` -- then use a closure might be very unsuitable.

Comment: So what? `doIt('doMe')` would have the exact same semantics as well, no need to wrap an anonymous function around it.

Comment: This would probably be the closes ever. and @deceze, what happens if it is an object method?

Comment: @ultimate See my answer for the PHP `callback` pseudo-type notation, which allows you to do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I'm looking for. It's neither elegant nor flexible. What if I want to pass global functions, object methods, and even functions from other namespaces?

Comment: @ultimate Well, **PHP is not elegant**.

Comment: @ultimatebuster, I'm unsure of why you marked this answer as correct. It does not create a reference to the function and it's horribly inflexible...

Comment: @macek No, this is exactly what the OP asked for.  It's using an anonymous function closure around the required call, so the function that receives this anonymous function as an argument doesn't need to know whether it received a class method or a global function.  This is by far the most flexible.

Comment: To clarify this, PHP knows different notations for `callable`s: `'globalFunctionName'`, `'ClassName::staticMethodName'`, `array('ClassName', 'staticMethodName')`, `array($object, 'methodName')`. All of those work with `call_user_func()`, `is_callable()` etc. - [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).
Still, they are technically not a reference (except the object instance in notation 4) but only an identifier.

Comment: Via an anonymous function: $f1 = function() {...}, $f2 = function() {...}, then you can assign $f = $f1 or $f = $f2 (e.g. as an argument to a calling function) and call it as $f(). Or you can use variable-functions like so: function f1(){...}, $f = "f1' and $f1(), by passing the name. Beware, $f1=f1 (no quotes) is not a reference to the function, it's a PHP string quirk, and the SAME as $f1='f1'.

Answer (score 18):

The problem with `call_user_func()` is that you're passing the return value of the function called, not the function itself.

I've run into this problem before too and here's the solution I came up with.

```
function funcRef($func){
  return create_function('', "return call_user_func_array('{$func}', func_get_args());");
}

function foo($a, $b, $c){
    return sprintf("A:%s B:%s C:%s", $a, $b, $c);
}

$b = funcRef("foo");

echo $b("hello", "world", 123);

//=> A:hello B:world C:123
```

[ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/vP6zkV)

Comment: Compared to and unlike the top voted and accepted answer from @user166390, this actually does what I want, letting me pass different C-style "function pointers" into a PHP function, and then call that function pointer with arguments. Thank you.

Comment: [`create_function()`](https://www.php.net/create_function) has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0, and removed as of PHP 8.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

No, functions are not first class values in PHP, they cannot be passed by their *name literal* (which is what you're asking for). Even anonymous functions or functions created via `create_function` are passed by an object or string reference. **Edit:** PHP 8.1 now has [first-class callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php), so this is no longer true for newer versions of PHP.

You can pass a name of a function as string, the name of an object method as `(object, string)` array or an anonymous function as object. None of these pass pointers or references, they just pass on the name of the function. All of these methods are known as the `callback` pseudo-type: http://php.net/callback

Comment: [This link about Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) disagrees about the functions not being first-class. (Granted "first-class" is a wide spectrum and flames can ensure, but anyway the objects can be *invoked* directly as per the examples -- but I don't use PHP, so am mostly fishing for a better explanation.) So how to get a the `test` into a function-object? E.g. Can do `$test2 = function () { test() }; call($test2)`? Or did I grossly miss something :p

Comment: @pst Sure, but that's all just syntactical sugar. Anonymous functions are implemented using the Closure class, so you're actually passing around an object, not a function. Note that the syntax for function names is `name`, while the syntax for "anonymous functions invocation" is `$name()`. You can never do `name()` on a "passed" or anonymous function.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if the observed semantics are the same. Using the "just sugar free of an object" argument then neither Scala or JavaScript would have first-class functions, but they do. (What is the difference between a *function* and an object that can be treated like a *function*? It depends upon language, but...)

Comment: @pst Arguably "first-class" is arguable, but you simply can't do what the OP wants to do. Period.

Comment: I disagree. "Works for me". See my reply.

Comment: PHP 8.1 does have [first-class callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php) now.

Answer (score 3):

```
function func1(){
    echo 'echo1 ';
    return 'return1';
}

function func2($func){
    echo 'echo2 ' . $func();
}

func2('func1');
```

Result:

```
echo1 echo2 return1
```

Comment: It will be really good if you could extend why does this work :) @dhbmarcos

Comment: This answer might be good enough for most use-cases, but is not correct for this question. Imagine func1 is not accessable from the scope of func2. In that case this solution would not work.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.4.4 (haven't tested lower or other versions), you can do exactly as you suggested.

Take this as an example:

```
function test ($func) {
    $func('moo');
}

function aFunctionToPass ($str) {
    echo $str;
}

test('aFunctionToPass');
```

The script will echo "moo" as if you called "aFunctionToPass" directly.

Comment: For me it gives a notice: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant aFunctionToPass - assumed 'aFunctionToPass'. When I passed function name as a string, the notice disappeared: test('aFunctionToPass');

Comment: Hmm, right that makes sense. I didn't check for warnings (I have them turned off right now) so thanks for that.

Comment: Updated to fix warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reference by assigning the function to a local variable when you declare it:

```
$test = function() {
    echo "hello world!";
};

function call($func){
    $func();
}

call($test);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, via an anonymous function. It does not use the "variable-function" construct, but rather $test as on Object. BTW, if you did $test = function(){...} and then $call = test without (!) quotes you still do not get a reference. $call() works because PHP allows an unquoted word as a string, and so it is a "variable-function", same as $call = 'test'

Comment: correction, I meant:  if you did function test(){...} and then $call = test without (!) quotes you still do not get a reference.

Answer (score 1):

A similar pattern of this Javascript first class function:

```
function add(first, second, callback){
    console.log(first+second);
    if (callback) callback();
}

function logDone(){
    console.log('done');
}

function logDoneAgain(){
    console.log('done Again');
}
add(2,3, logDone);
add(3,5, logDoneAgain);
```

Can be done in PHP (Tested with 5.5.9-1ubuntu on C9 IDE) in the following way:

```
// first class function
$add = function($first, $second, $callback) {
  echo "\n\n". $first+$second . "\n\n";
  if ($callback) $callback();
};

function logDone(){
  echo "\n\n done \n\n";
}
call_user_func_array($add, array(2, 3, logDone));
call_user_func_array($add, array(3, 6, function(){
  echo "\n\n done executing an anonymous function!";
}));
```

**Result**: 5 done 9 done executing an anonymous function!

Reference: https://github.com/zenithtekla/unitycloud/commit/873659c46c10c1fe5312f5cde55490490191e168

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 8.1, you can use [First-class callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php). For example, to reference a function named `test`, write the function name followed by `(...)`, like this:

```
$testFn = test(...);
// Then you can call it like a normal function:
// $testFn();
```

For your example, you can run:

```
call(test(...));
```

You can even reference methods:

```
call($obj->test(...));
```

As simple as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
$fun = 'test'; 
call($fun);
```

Comment: Can this be done with "getting a function-object" for `test`? Like `call(function () { test() })`? (I have no idea if that will even work). The problem with the code posted is that 'test' is an "unbound" string and is only resolved at time of invocation (e.g. by `call_user_function`) -- at which point it may be different or in an incorrect context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `call(test);`, use `call_user_func('test');`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears a bit unclear ***why* do you want to pass functions by reference?** Usually things are passed by reference only when the referenced data needs to be (potentially) modified by the function.

As PHP uses arrays or strings to refer functions, you could just pass an array or a string by reference and that would allow the function reference to be modified.

For example, you could do something like

```
<?php
$mysort = function($a, b) { return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1; };
adjust_sort_from_config($mysort); // modifies $mysort
do_something_with_data($mysort);
```

where

```
<?php
function load_my_configuration(&$fun)
{
  $sort_memory = new ...;
  ...
  $fun = [$sort_memory, "customSort"];
  // or simply
  $fun = function($a, b) { return (rand(1,10) < 4 ? 1 : -1; };
}
```

This works because there are three ways to refer to function in PHP via a variable:

- $name – the string $name contains the name of the function in global namespace that should be called
- array($object, $name) – refers to method called string $name of object $object.
- array($class, $name) – refers to static function string $name of class $class.

If I remember correctly, the methods and static functions pointed by these constructs must be public. The "[First-class callable syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/first_class_callable_syntax)" should improve this restriction given recent enough PHP version but it seems to be just some syntactic sugar around `Closure::fromCallable()`.

Anonymous functions work the same behind the scenes. You just don't see the literal random names of those functions anywhere but the reference to an anonymous function is just a value of a variable, too.