# How to use anonymous functions before PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have a class that uses 5.3 feature anonymous function (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types/blob/master/jw_custom_posts.php), but there is a problem, on the server I can not upgrade to 5.3. Is there any simple workaround to get rid of anonymous functions or do I need to rewrite whole class?

Comment: Hopefully you'll find a workaround in this case, but nevertheless it is essential to determine dependencies/requirements of external libraries before committing to using them :-)

Comment: Yes, didn't knew that server can't handle it. Rewrote the code with core wordpress.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem with just naming the function and calling it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: most of the anonymous functions in that linked file are closures, so that won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Change the hosting with PHP version supporting anonymous functions
- Re-write your code so it works with version of PHP you have

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for pre PHP 5.3 is to use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

It is ugly as hell and akin to `eval()`, but it's closest to functionality without defining another function and passing a pointer to it.

Comment: With such a big anonymous function (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types/blob/master/jw_custom_posts.php#L159) it will be hard to use create_function, enclosing all the PHP code in a string... You should create your own function and passing its name to `admin_init`.