# Assigning a function to the variable without calling this function

Tags: php, function, variables

I want to assigning a function to the variable without calling this function when assigning it to variable.

```
function abc(){
  echo 'abc';
}
```

and in PHP

```
$variable=abc();
```

and then echo variable with function

```
echo $variable;
```

**EDIT***

Because I want to have variable like this

```
 $variable = $something[0].$function.$something[1];
```

Comment: If you don' want to call it then don't call it. `$variable = function () { echo('abc'); };` However, you cannot `echo($variable);` because PHP only knows how to `echo` strings and it doesn't know how to convert a function to a string (it does't make any sense).

Comment: [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475154/1229023).

Comment: The thing is that I want to have value of the function in variable and call it later, not when I'm assigning it to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is called **Variable functions** in PHP and is done like this.

```
function foo() {
    return "Hello I am foo()\n";
}

$func = 'foo';
echo $func();        // This calls foo()
```

See the [PHP Manual page for Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php#functions.variable-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$variable = function() {
    echo 'abc';
};
```

And then call it like:

```
$variable();
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/232135)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
$variable=function(){
  echo 'abc';
};
$variable();
```

or

```
function abc(){
echo 'abc';
}
$variable="abc";
 $variable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to capture what is being echoed (are you using Wordpress?):

```
ob_start();
abc();
$variable = ob_get_clean();

echo $variable;
```

Starts a buffer to hold the output and then gets the output from the buffer.

Comment: I'm building my own website. I did it like you said and it gives me "1". The thing is that I want to have value of the function in variable and call it later, not when I'm assigning it to variable.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I typed ob_start(); on beginning but on the end instead of ob_get_clean(); I typed ob_start(); once again...